# Can I have my web hosting company redirect all requests to an IP address? (from blahblah.example.com to 123.456.789.012)

Tags: networking, vpn, ip, web-hosting

I have a web hosting account, from FatCow. They gave me a subdomain, `blahblah.fatcow.com`. Would it be possible to simply redirect all traffic from that subdomain to my home IP address?

For example, I have a VPN server setup on my home computer that's accessible from everywhere. Currently, I type in the full IP address, say `123.456.789.012`, to get to it. Could I somehow type in `blahblah.fatcow.com` into the form rather than  `123.456.789.012` and still have the traffic directed to my home IP address? In other words, could I configure the that address in a way where all anyone, who was spying on my internet connection, could see is that I have a connection to `blahblah.fatcow.com` rather than `123.456.789.012`?

FYI, that's not my actual subdomain address.

Comment: Why would you want to, the thing you are paying for is the server they provide for at their ip address. If you want a address to point at your home computer just use any [free dynamic DNS service](http://dnslookup.me/dynamic-dns/). Also it looks like what you really want is a [Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) (possibly you could set one up at blahblah.fatcow.com with the service plan you are paying for, i don't know how their service works).

Comment: What you want is indeed possible.  Purchase a domain, setup and publish the DNS information, and then connect to your VPN.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I do have a proxy set up already. The problem with it is that it, on occasion, messes up the webpage. For example, I can't log into Google.

Comment: You can call your "Dynamic Name" what you want, with that Name they can find out the IP...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that it is impossible to achieve your goal. Your goal is:

> ... anyone, who was spying on my internet connection, could see is that I have a connection to blahblah.fatcow.com rather than 123.456.789.012?

But the problem is, it's very easy to figure out IP address behind a domain (that's what DNS is for)

Back to your question, there might be some setting in FatCow's admin panel (I don't have account there). Look for DNS Management, from there you might be able to change where `blahblah.fatcow.com` points to. If it's not possible, you can just create a sub domain, for example, `sub.blahblah.fatcow.com` to point to your IP address.

Comment: There wasn't, but thanks for your explanation about DNS.